# Receive 400 Bad Request from Image Resizer request in Azure

Tags: azure, imageresizer

ImageResizer is running as an Azure virtual application (after ImageResizer hotfix).  This runs fine in Azure emulation but is having problems in Azure cloud.  Image Resizer is working fine if no query string arguments are specified and the url redirects to blob storage, but if a query string argument is specified then I receive a 400 "Bad Request" error.

Below is a screenshot of my browser:

[image]

My Azure instance is running Windows Server 2012.  I have also disabled the DiskCache plugin to reduce the problem.

Comment: Let me know if the hotfix I sent helped.

Comment: Yes - hot fix 3.3.5.805 does the trick! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem as You. I used fiddler to see if I could figure out what went wrong and I think I fixed it. It's a problem with AzureReader2 and how it concatenates URL'S.

A specific example from fiddler is this URL: http://xxx.blob.core.windows.net//card-images/14_main_image.png

As you can see it got two slashes in a row which gives you the 400 "bad request".

I downloaded the sourcecode for AzureReader2 and replaced all occurrences of "CloudBlobClient.BaseUri.OriginalString" with "CloudBlobClient.BaseUri.OriginalString.TrimEnd('/', '\')"

I don't know if it's the best fix, but at least it's working until a better fix comes. If you are interested, I can send you the compiled dll.

Best Regards
Martin

Comment: thanks Martin - It appears that your fix essentially fixes the problem and that this change is now part of hot fix 3.3.5.805.

Comment: Yep, Martin's solution hit the nail on the head. FYI, @martin-larsen, you get a free support incident and a big bug bounty reward for including the fix! E-mail support@imageresizing.net

Comment: I am having same issue, but it is only when I try to deploy locally works fine on server. Any work around ?

Answer (score 0):

*I would have added this as a comment in reply to user2486535, but my StackOverflow rep is not sufficient for posting comments yet...*

You are probably getting the 400 Bad Request at this time because the latest version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (3.0.2.0) is not compatible with the current Storage Emulator released with the Windows Azure SDK (2.2).

It's explained at the bottom of this article, under "Storage Emulator Guidance":
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx

As of January 27, Microsoft has released a preview version of the Windows Azure Storage Emulator (2.2.1) that is compatible with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (3.0.2.0):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/01/27/windows-azure-storage-emulator-2-2-1-preview-release-with-support-for-2013-08-15-version.aspx

Hopefully this helps you get by until the next official release of the Windows Azure SDK.